# mysql select data by relation of parameters

Tags: mysql, select

some help here please with (advanced) mysql. Example illustrates the issue much better. So..

I have a predefined value pair table PARTNERS with partner1 and partner2 columns. And then there is another table PROJECTS which has partner1 and partner2 columns.

So, I want to select all PROJECTS where columns partner1 and partner2 are within the actual partners table described above.

Obviously, I cannot simply indicate "where partner1=... and/or partner2=..." because there would be no check of whether those two are partners (as defined in the PARTNERS table). (Just in case: there are projects with partner1 and partner2 not in the partner relationships.)

I don't think that kind of query is possible at all since it has the condition stored in the result. But would be happy if one can prove otherwise.
Thanks

Comment: I don't see why you can't just join the 2 tables on Partner1 = partner1 and partner2 = partner2...  Could you show a real example with table values and the expected result

Comment: I thought you would understand that this type of question is irrelevant because the example is mush simpler than what is actually in the system. Note above "Just in case: there are projects with partner1 and partner2 not in the partner relationships."

Comment: What?  All you need is to join the two tables (much like octern showed below) unless you are doing a poor job of explaining your needs, and we are misunderstanding your problem.

Comment: sorry... you were right... thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need a query that will give you rows from PROJECTS where partner 1 and partner 2 are both the same as they are in any row in PARTNERS. So do an inner join:

```
SELECT * FROM projects
INNER JOIN partners
    ON projects.partner1 = partners.partner1
    AND projects.partner2 = partners.partner2
```

If you're up for restructuring your tables, it might make more sense to assign a unique ID to every row in PARTNERS, and use that ID in the PROJECTS table. That way instead of storing two columns of redundant data, you just have one column indicating which pair of students is on the project.

Comment: @StefanH Thanks for fixing my typos (:

Comment: No problem, you changed it back and were putting up quite the fight though :P

Comment: I was making an unrelated edit at the time, and for some reason SO kept telling me that the entire page didn't exist, or sending me to the human verification screen... thanks for your perseverance.

Comment: ok, ive just realized that I need the leftovers actually, i.e. those projects that are with NON-partners, excluding the partner projects... do i simply "p1!=p1 and p2!=p2"? Thanks

Comment: I don't think that will work, though it might be instructive to try that and see what it does return. For that you should select from projects and do a left join on partners, using the same join criteria as above. This will put NULL in the partner fields for every project where the students aren't partners, and you can put that in your where clause.

Comment: You could use the exact same query and just replace = with <> and replace AND with OR.

Comment: @StefanH Wouldn't that need to be XOR? Otherwise every record in PROJECTS would be matched to every record in PARTNERS where both participants were different.

Comment: @octern Good point, The left join and check for nulls is the right way to go.